# how to make layout clickable programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, clickable

I am creating a RelativeLayout programmatically, and thus, I need to add this xml attribute: `android:clickable="true"` programmatically.

How can this be done? thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to use `setClickable(true)`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29)